# i want to get status of switch from server. values i get from server is 0 or 1 based on that i have to set position of switch and do the switching

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-switch

i am using setOncheckListner. when i change switch position to ON i am able to pass value to sever and switch state is changed. when the page refreshes as the values will be loading from server,switch comes to OFF state.

Areator_On.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                WebService.invokeGridMonitor(constants.U_name,constants.U_pass ,isChecked,"","DefaultData");

                Log.d("ApplicationAdapter", " Switch State "+isChecked);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Are you setting the checked state of the CompoundButton when the view is created using `setChecked(valueFromServer == 1)`?

Comment: no how to set it i don't know

Comment: Like I said `Areator_On.setChecked(valueFromServer == 1)`

Comment: i tried but not working actually now the switch state is ON in web application. i also have to represent it same and and able to off the switch from mobile app